# Connecting the symptom name and description data to the specific patient

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to build a patient database that renders the `Symptom_name` and `Symptom_description` to the document object model.

Each name and description should be attached to the patient for which it was created, however each time the fields are populated and saved the `Symptom_name` and `Symptom_description` is seen in all the patients created which is not what I want.

In the below image both James and Jimmy has the same `Symptom_name` and `Symptom_description` however I only clicked the James Timmerson `a` tag to add the `Symptom_name` and `Symptom_description`.

How do I ensure that only James Timmerson has that `symptom_relation` data.

Essentially I want to ensure the relevant symptoms connect to the relevant patients.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

> Here is my code :

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from Identity import settings
import datetime



# Create your models here.

class Identity_unique(models.Model):
    NIS = models.CharField(max_length = 200, primary_key = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    Timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)    
    First_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 80, null = True,  )    
    Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 80, null = True, )    
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True)    
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = False, blank = True, null = True)    
    Contact = models.CharField(max_length = 15, null = True)

class Symptom_relation(models.Model): 
    Symptom_name = models.CharField(max_length = 80, default = '')    
    Symptom_description = models.TextField(max_length = 1000, default = '')    
    Unique_Identity = models.ManyToManyField(Identity_unique, blank = False)
```

***views.py***

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView
from nesting.forms import Identity_Form, Symptom_Form
from nesting.models import Identity_unique, Symptom_relation


class Identity_view(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'nesting/nesting.html'

    def get(self, request):    
        form = Identity_Form()    
        Identities = Identity_unique.objects.filter(user = request.user)    
        var = {'form': form, 'Identities': Identities}    
        return render(request, self.template_name, var)

    def post(self, request):    
        form  = Identity_Form(request.POST or None)    
        content = None

        if form.is_valid():    
            NIS = form.save(commit = False)
            NIS.user = request.user
            NIS.save()

            content = form.cleaned_data['NIS']

            form = Identity_Form()    
            return redirect('nesting:nesting')

        var = {'form': form, 'content': content}
        return render(request,self.template_name, var)


class Identity_nest_list_view(TemplateView):
    model = Identity_unique
    template_name = 'nesting/Identity_nest.html'   

    def get(self, request):   
        form = Identity_Form()    
        Identities = Identity_unique.objects.filter(user = request.user).order_by('-Timestamp')
        var = {'form':form, 'Identities': Identities}
        return render(request, self.template_name, var)





class Symptoms_document_view(TemplateView):    
    model = Symptom_relation    
    template_name = 'nesting/Symptoms_list.html'

    def get(self, request):    
        form = Symptom_Form()    
        Symptoms_desc = Symptom_relation.objects.all()    

        var = {'form':form, 'Symptoms_desc':Symptoms_desc}    
        return render(request, self.template_name, var)    

    def post(self, request):    
        form = Symptom_Form(request.POST or None)    
        Symptom_content = None

        if form.is_valid():    
            Symptom_description = form.save(commit = False)
            Symptom_description.user = request.user
            Symptom_description.save()

            Symptom_content = form.cleaned_data['Symptom_description']

            form = Symptom_Form()    
            redirect('nesting:nesting')

        var = {'form': form, 'Symptom_content': Symptom_content}    
        return render(request, self.template_name, var)


class Medical_History_nest_view(TemplateView):
    model = Symptom_relation    
    template_name = 'nesting/Medical_History_nest.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = Symptom_Form()
        Symptoms_desc = Symptom_relation.objects.all()  
        var = {'form':form, 'Symptoms_desc':Symptoms_desc}

        return render(request, self.template_name, var)
```

***forms.py***

```
from django import forms
from nesting.models import Identity_unique
from nesting.models import Symptom_relation


class Identity_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    NIS = forms.CharField(
                    widget=forms.TextInput(
                            attrs={

                                'placeholder': 'Enter NIS',
                                'class' : 'form-control'
                            }
                )
    )

    First_Name = forms.CharField(
                widget=forms.TextInput(
                        attrs={
                            'placeholder': 'Enter First Name',
                            'class' : 'form-control'
                        }
            )
    )
    Last_Name = forms.CharField(

       widget=forms.TextInput(
               attrs={

                   'placeholder': 'Enter Last Name',
                   'class' : 'form-control'
               }
        )
    )

    location = forms.CharField(

            widget=forms.TextInput(
                        attrs= {

                        'placeholder':'Enter Address',
                        'class':'form-control'

                        }
            )
    )

    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(

            required = False,
                widget=forms.TextInput(
                            attrs= {

                            'placeholder' : 'Enter birth day',
                            'class':'form-control'

                            }
                ),
        )

    Contact = forms.CharField(

                    widget=forms.TextInput(
                                attrs= {

                                'placeholder':'Enter Contact',
                                'class':'form-control'

                                }
                    )
            )


    class Meta:

        model = Identity_unique

        fields = ('NIS', 'First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'location', 'date_of_birth', 'Contact',)




class Symptom_Form(forms.ModelForm):


                Symptom_description = forms.CharField(

                widget=forms.Textarea(
                            attrs= {

                            'placeholder':'Symptom description',
                            'class':'form-control'

                            }
                )
    )

                Symptom_name = forms.CharField(


                    widget=forms.TextInput(
                                attrs= {

                                'placeholder':'Symptom Name',
                                'class':'form-control'

                                }
                    )

                )

                class Meta:

                    model = Symptom_relation

                    fields = ('Symptom_name', 'Symptom_description',)
```

***Edit***

***templates***

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    {% block head %}
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>See patient</title>
  </head>

  {% endblock %}
  <body>


{% block body %}

<div class = "row" style = "margin-top: 80px;">

  <div class="col-sm" >

      <nav class =" "  >

        <ul class = "nav flex-column">

                         <li class = "nav-item"><a class = "nav-link" href = "{% url 'nesting:nesting'%}" ><small>Create  Identity </small></a></li>
                         <!-- <li class = "nav-item"><a class = "nav-link" href = "#"><small>Update </small></a></li>
                         <li class = "nav-item"><a class = "nav-link" href = "#"><small>Move to Trash</small> </a></li> -->
          </ul>

      </nav>
  </div>

  <div class = "col-sm" >

{% for Identity in Identities %}

    <div class = "card " style = "margin-top: 20px;" >

            <ul class = "list-group list-group-flush">
               <li class = "list-group-item"> <small class = "text-muted">Created On : {{Identity.Timestamp}}</small></li>

              <li class = "list-group-item"><a class = "nav-link" href = "{% url 'nesting:Medical_History_nest' %}" >{{Identity.First_Name}}  {{Identity.Last_Name}} </a> <p>NIS:  {{ Identity.NIS }}</p></li>
              <li class = "list-group-item"><p> <small>Contact: {{ Identity.Contact}}</small></p></a></li>
              <li class = "list-group-item"><p> <small>Birthday: {{ Identity.date_of_birth}}</small></p></a></li>
              <li class = "list-group-item"><a class = "nav-link" href = "{%url 'nesting:Symptoms_nest_list'%}" ><small>Create Medical State </small></a></li>

            </ul>
    </div>
          {% endfor %}
  </div>

<div class="col-sm" ></div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show the template? Make sure you have the right relation to show what you expect

Comment: @MauricioCortazar I added the template

Comment: Where is the part of the template in which you render Symptoms for each user? Or do you render them by js?